# Combining .txt files but limiting the combined file into sized chunks

Tags: linux, shell-script, kubuntu

I have a batch of `.txt` files I want to combine so I can import into another program. This program is limited by 2GB data packets at a time but the total of the files will be 20GB.

Is it possible to combine the `.txt` files, limiting to 2GB each time, giving a total of 10x 2GB combined files? I'd like to add it to a script.

I am running script with the commands as:

```
cat $full/blank/ascii/*/*xyz > $full/blank/ascii/output.txt
split -b 2000m $full/blank/ascii/ouput.txt
```

But when I run this, it says

```
line 1: /blank/ascii/output.txt: no such file or directory.
```

I have the full pathway at the start of the file too. Is it also possible to split a file and send the output to seperate folder?

Comment: What's wrong with putting the commands into your script? Why won't that work for you?

Comment: I am running script with the cmds as: cat $full/blank/ascii/*/*xyz > $full/blank/ascii/output.txt then split -b 2000m $full/blank/ascii/ouput.txt    when i run this, it says line 1: /blank/ascii/output.txt: no such file or directory.   I havefull pathway at the start of the file too

Comment: Please would you put that update [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/549107/edit), where it can be seen and easily read by everyone.

Comment: The error message you see would indicate that the expression `$full` you are using in your path specifications is undefined (notice the path it reports starts with `/blank`?). Perhaps if you posted the script, too, the community might be able to help in debugging it.

Comment: thank you, I corrected my $full path, it is now running. just need to send the new files to the correct folder

Comment: Are you sure it runs correctly now? You have `output.txt` in the first and `ouput.txt` in the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined `$full`, so the command `cat $full/blank/ascii/*/*xyz > $full/blank/ascii/output.txt` is being evaluated with that as an empty string:

```
cat /blank/ascii/*/*xyz > /blank/ascii/output.txt
```

Furthermore, since the interpreter reports that this is on line 1 of your script, I would guess you've not got a `#!` interpreter defined there yet. I would really recommend you get used to providing one of these at the start of every script you write.

```
#!/bin/bash

full=/path/somewhere/...

cat $full/blank/ascii/*/*xyz > $full/blank/ascii/output.txt
split -b 2000m $full/blank/ascii/ouput.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the currect $full path and it now runs. I just need out to edit my split cmd to send output files to seperate folder with a .txt prefix

Comment: thank you for the help. Would you know how i can use the split command to send created files to a separate folder with a new .txt prefix? many thanks

Comment: @AJOS `man split` and look for the `PREFIX` option